# Most efficient way of extracting the index of bits set to 1

Tags: c, performance, memory, bit, chess

I'm writing a chess program and I use 64bit bitmask to represent if there is a piece on each square of the board. Whenever I need to iterate through the board and do something for all pieces, I look at the bitmask, find the "index" (shift amount) of the bits set to 1, and then look at the board to see which piece it is.

That procedure may or may not be the best, but I'm finding that this function (on_bits) which extracts the bits takes up to 5% of the program running time! Even when taking the amount of times it gets called into account, it's still pretty slow. So I'm looking for a good solution to this. I'm posting both of my attempts.

Original:

```
int on_bits(u64 x, u8 *arr) {
    int ret = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (x) {
        while (!(x&0xffffffff)) {
            x >>= 32;
            i += 32;
        }

        while (!(x&0xff)) {
            x >>= 8;
            i += 8;
        }

        while (!(x&1)) {
            x >>= 1;
            i++;
        }

        arr[ret++] = i;
        x >>= 1;
        i++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

New version, runs faster with compiler optimizations and unrolling. Around 2x faster than previous one.

```
#define B(n)    (((u64)0xff)<<((8*n)))
#define b(n)    (((u64)1<<(n)))

int on_bits(u64 x, u8 *arr) {
    int ret = 0;

    if (x & (B(0) | B(1) | B(2) | B(3))) {
        if (x & B(0)) {
            if (x & b(0)) arr[ret++] = 0;
            if (x & b(1)) arr[ret++] = 1;
            if (x & b(2)) arr[ret++] = 2;
            if (x & b(3)) arr[ret++] = 3;
            if (x & b(4)) arr[ret++] = 4;
            if (x & b(5)) arr[ret++] = 5;
            if (x & b(6)) arr[ret++] = 6;
            if (x & b(7)) arr[ret++] = 7;
        }
        if (x & B(1)) {
            if (x & b(8)) arr[ret++] = 8;
            if (x & b(9)) arr[ret++] = 9;
            if (x & b(10)) arr[ret++] = 10;
            if (x & b(11)) arr[ret++] = 11;
            if (x & b(12)) arr[ret++] = 12;
            if (x & b(13)) arr[ret++] = 13;
            if (x & b(14)) arr[ret++] = 14;
            if (x & b(15)) arr[ret++] = 15;
        }
        if (x & B(2)) {
            if (x & b(16)) arr[ret++] = 16;
            if (x & b(17)) arr[ret++] = 17;
            if (x & b(18)) arr[ret++] = 18;
            if (x & b(19)) arr[ret++] = 19;
            if (x & b(20)) arr[ret++] = 20;
            if (x & b(21)) arr[ret++] = 21;
            if (x & b(22)) arr[ret++] = 22;
            if (x & b(23)) arr[ret++] = 23;
        }
        if (x & B(3)) {
            if (x & b(24)) arr[ret++] = 24;
            if (x & b(25)) arr[ret++] = 25;
            if (x & b(26)) arr[ret++] = 26;
            if (x & b(27)) arr[ret++] = 27;
            if (x & b(28)) arr[ret++] = 28;
            if (x & b(29)) arr[ret++] = 29;
            if (x & b(30)) arr[ret++] = 30;
            if (x & b(31)) arr[ret++] = 31;
        }
    }
    if (x & (B(4) | B(5) | B(6) | B(7))) {
        if (x & B(4)) {
            if (x & b(32)) arr[ret++] = 32;
            if (x & b(33)) arr[ret++] = 33;
            if (x & b(34)) arr[ret++] = 34;
            if (x & b(35)) arr[ret++] = 35;
            if (x & b(36)) arr[ret++] = 36;
            if (x & b(37)) arr[ret++] = 37;
            if (x & b(38)) arr[ret++] = 38;
            if (x & b(39)) arr[ret++] = 39;
        }
        if (x & B(5)) {
            if (x & b(40)) arr[ret++] = 40;
            if (x & b(41)) arr[ret++] = 41;
            if (x & b(42)) arr[ret++] = 42;
            if (x & b(43)) arr[ret++] = 43;
            if (x & b(44)) arr[ret++] = 44;
            if (x & b(45)) arr[ret++] = 45;
            if (x & b(46)) arr[ret++] = 46;
            if (x & b(47)) arr[ret++] = 47;
        }
        if (x & B(6)) {
            if (x & b(48)) arr[ret++] = 48;
            if (x & b(49)) arr[ret++] = 49;
            if (x & b(50)) arr[ret++] = 50;
            if (x & b(51)) arr[ret++] = 51;
            if (x & b(52)) arr[ret++] = 52;
            if (x & b(53)) arr[ret++] = 53;
            if (x & b(54)) arr[ret++] = 54;
            if (x & b(55)) arr[ret++] = 55;
        }
        if (x & B(7)) {
            if (x & b(56)) arr[ret++] = 56;
            if (x & b(57)) arr[ret++] = 57;
            if (x & b(58)) arr[ret++] = 58;
            if (x & b(59)) arr[ret++] = 59;
            if (x & b(60)) arr[ret++] = 60;
            if (x & b(61)) arr[ret++] = 61;
            if (x & b(62)) arr[ret++] = 62;
            if (x & b(63)) arr[ret++] = 63;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

(There's no doubt which one is simpler, though :))

So, any ideas to improve this? Or is it a dead end?
For reference, the function gets called 30 millions times in a very short benchmark.

Thanks

EDIT: It's not a requirement that the output array is sorted. Also, a super fast 'which is the first bit set' function can be ok, but my attempts at that were super slow compared to this (I used the fls function from the Linux kernel)

Comment: See: https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan There's is hardware support for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to return the positions of all set bits in a 64-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713017/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-return-the-positions-of-all-set-bits-in-a-64-bit-inte)

Comment: You should probably replace the macros with inline functions to improve code quality at no other disadvantage.

Comment: @usr sure, it was a quick mock-up actually. Thanks

Comment: Why there is cpu operation for this, I mean, logical circuits which evaluate this faster?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gcc, it has useful builtins to do what you want

```
— Built-in Function: int __builtin_ffs (int x)
    Returns one plus the index of the least significant 1-bit of x, or if x is zero, returns zero.
— Built-in Function: int __builtin_ffsl (long)
    Similar to __builtin_ffs, except the argument type is long.
— Built-in Function: int __builtin_ffsll (long long)
    Similar to __builtin_ffs, except the argument type is long long.
```

Comment: Yes, but if I use those functions to iterate, everything is actually slower. I just ran a test using these as suggested in chessprogramming.com. I think it's better to get all the indexes in one go. I'm running some better tests right now and I'll come back to you

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, there are reasonable answers here...

But...

5% is *nothing*. If you cut it in half, what have you gained? Peanuts. There's something else (I'll bet) that you can do to save more time, and then something else after that. (Got any `malloc` & `free` in there?) Cut out enough of those, and you'll speed up the whole thing, to where that 5% in `on-bits` will grow until it's worth worrying about, 'cause you've sliced away other fat.

You don't say what profiling approach you use to get that 5% figure, but most profilers (*especially* `gprof`) blissfully fail to tell you what the biggest speedup opportunities are, leading you to think your code is so tight that something taking 5% is worth concentrating on. [*This explains it in more detail.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also see Amdahl's law. Even if you make it take 0 time, you're talking about a 5% speedup. Not a big deal.

Comment: @Patrick: Right. Then the speedup ratio would be 100/95. If it originally took a minute and 40 seconds, it would shrink to a minute and 35 seconds. BFD.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider turning the problem around and rather than constructing an array of which bits are on, to simply asking whether bit X is set, you may be able to cut down on the time. If you need to create the array, then looping though all bits with the following may prove faster:

```
/* (bit == 1) ? return 1 : 0, on error return -1 */
inline int bit_isset (unsigned long bf, int n)
{
    if ((unsigned long) n > sizeof (unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT -1)
        return -1;

    return ((bf >> n) & 0x1) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Here you can simply pass `x` and then the bit you are interested in to bit_isset, e.g. to test whether the 49th bit is set `bit_isset(x, 49)`. You can try constructing the `ret` array with this function and test how the time compares by iterating `0<n<63` in a for loop or similar.

Comment: Hi, this performs similar to the first option. So it's 2x slower than my second method.

Comment: How does ditching the bounds check do and just assigning `ret[n]=((x >> n) & 0x1) ? 1 : 0;` compare? (changed to meet your vars)

Comment: I did ditch the bounds check as my code guarantees it'll be ok.